# Determinar o consumo de memória

Tags: desempenho, memória, golang

Olá, sou iniciante em Go e estou com dificuldades em determinar quanta memória o código em Go precisou para executar algum código. Eu fiz a função memory() que até retorna algo, mas não sei como seria para trazer o retorno que quero, seria tipo: o código precisou de 15MB para ser executado, por exemplo, teria como fazer isso? Agradeço desde já!

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func ack(m, n uint) uint {
    if m == 0 {
        return n + 1
    } else if n == 0 {
        return ack(m - 1, 1)
    } else {
        return ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1))
    }
}

func memory(){
    for {
        var m runtime.MemStats
        runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)
        log.Printf("\nAlloc = %v\nTotalAlloc = %v\nSys = %v\nNumGC = %v\n\n", m.Alloc / 1024, m.TotalAlloc / 1024, m.Sys / 1024, m.NumGC)
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {

    var inicio = time.Now().UnixNano()
    fmt.Println(ack(1,2))
    var fim = time.Now().UnixNano()
    fmt.Println(fim - inicio)

    memory()

}
```

Comment: Você precisa de stack, heap, ou tempo?

Comment: Preciso do total de memória que foi utilizado para executar o código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta é antiga, mas acho que sempre vale responder.

Sugiro dar uma olhada no pacote de teste (https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) nativo de Go. Há várias funções interessantes para esse tipo de coisa.

Para seu caso especifico, usaria a funcionalidade de test de Benchmark, que te dá informações como alocação de memória, assim como, claro, o bench da sua função.

Para usar a funcionalidade de benchmark in Go, crie um novo arquivo seguindo o formato:

*[nome do arquivo]_test.go*

Nesse arquivo, importe o package de test e crie uma função no seguinte formato:

*func Benchmark[nome da função](b *testing.B) {}*

É crucial que a função comece com o termo **Benchmark** pois de outra forma Go não vai reconhecer essa como uma função de Benchmark e dará erro.

Segue um exemplo com o seu código:

```
func ack(m, n uint) uint {
    if m == 0 {
        return n + 1
    } else if n == 0 {
        return ack(m-1, 1)
    } else {
        return ack(m-1, ack(m, n-1))
    }
}

func BenchmarkAck(b *testing.B) {
    ack(1, 2)
}
```

Para rodar use o comando:  go test -bench=. com a flag -benchmem para ver informações de alocação de memória etc:

```
go test -bench=. -benchmem
```